# JavaScript - найти ключ зная его значение

Tags: javascript, ооп

Надо найти в объекте ключ, зная только его значение. Я написал код, но он не находит ключи находящиеся в под-объекте. Вот сам код:

```
Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function(value) {
    for(var prop in this) {
        if(this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
             if(this[prop] === value)
                 return prop;
        }
    }
}
```

Первый пример (работает корректно):

```js
Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function(value) {
  for (var prop in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (this[prop] === value)
        return prop;
    }
  }
}

var foobar = {
  foo: 4,
  bar: 7
}
document.write(foobar.getKeyByValue(7));
```

Второй пример (работает не корректно):

```js
Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function(value) {
  for (var prop in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (this[prop] === value)
        return prop;
    }
  }
}

var foobar = {
  foo: 4,
  bar: {
    baz: 7
  }
}
document.write(foobar.getKeyByValue(7));
```

Почему во втором примере не находит значение и как это исправить?

Comment: не работает, потому что во втором случае у вас свойство объекта - объект, нужно зайти в этот объект и там искать свойства нужные

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что для поиска вглубь нужна рекурсия.

```js
Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function(value, objs) {

  // защита от циклических ссылок
  if (!objs)
    objs = [];

  for (var prop in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (this[prop] === value) {
        return prop;
      } else if (typeof this[prop] === "object" && objs.indexOf(this[prop]) == -1) {
        objs.push(this[prop]);
        var res = this[prop].getKeyByValue(value, objs);
        if (res)
          return prop + "." + res; //за дополнительные баллы оценки - выведем цепочку названий ключей
      }
    }
  }
}

var foobar = {
  foo: 4,
  bar: {
    baz: 7
  }
}
console.log(foobar.getKeyByValue(7));
```